# r creation diagonal matrix from vector with use upper.tri function

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have vector

```
vector= c(4,6,2,9)
```

I need to get diagonal matrix looking like this (second column should contatain vector scrolled down on one element, third - on two elements etc.):

```
4 0 0 0
6 4 0 0
2 6 4 0
9 2 6 4
```

As I could undestand I should use upper.tri.

I tried this one :

```
vector = c(4,6,2,9)
vector_length=length(a)
MATRIX= matrix(0, vector_length, vector_length)
MATRIX[!upper.tri(MATRIX)]=vector 
MATRIX
```

and failed because the  result was

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    0    0    0
[2,]    6    4    0    0
[3,]    2    6    9    0
[4,]    9    2    4    6
```

How should I use this function correctly? And How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
MATRIX = matrix(c(vector, 0), vector_length, vector_length)
# ignore warning about uneven recycling
MATRIX[upper.tri(MATRIX)] = 0
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    0    0    0
# [2,]    6    4    0    0
# [3,]    2    6    4    0
# [4,]    9    2    6    4
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the fact that `data.table::shift` is vectorized in the `n` argument

```
do.call(cbind, data.table::shift(vector, seq(vector_length) - 1, fill = 0))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    0    0    0
# [2,]    6    4    0    0
# [3,]    2    6    4    0
# [4,]    9    2    6    4
```

Or using `row()` and `col()` in base R

```
m <- matrix(0, vector_length, vector_length)
diagn <- row(m) - col(m) + 1
m[diagn > 0] <- vector[diagn[diagn > 0]]

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    0    0    0
# [2,]    6    4    0    0
# [3,]    2    6    4    0
# [4,]    9    2    6    4
```